# Adding condition in conditional split

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, conditional-split

I am trying to follow the process below to transform data from flat file to DB.
I also have an update_dt_tm column in the source. I need to put a condition that if updt_dt_tm is between last 10 mints it updates all the columns in that table.

How can I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isQzC.png)

I am just trying to add a condition in the conditional split.

Source table : 
person_id,person_name,address,country,updt_dt,amount

Destination Table :
person_id,person_name,person_address,person_country,person_updt_tm,person_amt

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a simple thing.

I just needed to go and put this condition

```
(DT_DBDATE)[Copy of updt_dt] >= (DT_DBDATE)"01/07/2018"
```

Comment: you might want to consider dateadd("m",-10,getdate()) instead of hardcoding. I am assuming "mints" means months in your question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/dateadd-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017